# Show that there is a $\xi\in(a,b)$ s.t. $\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,dx=f(\xi)\int_a^b g(x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f$ and $g$ are continuous on an interval $[a,b]$ and $g$ is nonnegative, show that there is a number $\xi \in (a,b)$ such that
$$\int_a^b f(x)g(x) \; dx = f(\xi) \int_a^b g(x) \; dx.$$

I understand the proof for the case when $\xi \in[a,b],$ however, I'm not sure how to proceed when $\xi \in(a,b).$

Comment: Your understanding is pointless. Why divide cases like that?

Comment: @Zhanxiong, I'm not sure why you would want to divide cases as such. The author of the text I'm following gave two different cases.

Comment: My point is, it's unnecessary to divide cases. A correct answer has been given below.

Comment: You are right the proof for $\xi \in (a, b)$ is different from $\xi \in [a, b]$ and normally this fact is overlooked by many. A proper proof is based on Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and mean value theorem for differential calculus. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1916448/72031 and http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1840008/72031

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$, it achieves a maximum and minimum value. Call them $M$ and $m$ respectively. Then, since $g$ is non-negative:

$$m\int_a^bg(x)dx\le \int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx\le M\int_a^b g(x)dx$$

and therefore:

$$m\le  \frac{\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx}{\int_a^b g(x)dx}\le M$$

Now apply the intermediate value theorem.

EDIT: We've assumed above that $\int_a^bg(x)dx>0$. In case said integral vanishes, since $g$ is continuous and non-negative, it follows that $g\equiv 0$ (can you why?). Then $fg\equiv 0$ and the theorem is trivial.

Comment: Should the denominator be $\int_a^b g(x)\,dx$ in the last line?

Comment: It should, yes :P.

Comment: It would be good to mention why the nonnegativity of $g$ is important. Also, $\int_a^b g=0$ is possible, so best to deal with that at the beginning.

Comment: @zhw. You're probably right. I'll add that case to my answer.

Comment: Why are we applying intermediate value theorem?

Comment: @Setsss The ugly quotient of integrals is a number between the maximum and minimum of $g$. The IVT tell's you that said value is achieved by $f$ at some point of $[a,b]$.

Comment: Would that still apply to the open interval (a,b)? Since that's what we're after?